# How can i reference this from interface

Tags: java, apache-spark

Hi I would like to do something like this but the problem is getting and that this cannot be reference from static context . for example (simplified) :

```
public interface Foo {
     public String fooName = this.getClass().getName();
}
```

how can I do it ?

Comment: All fields in interfaces are always `public` and `static`. Thus, in a variable declaration with intialization, you cannot access `this`.

Comment: Instead of a variable, use a final default method.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to get with this?

Comment: @Taschi Im pretty sure final isn't legal on a default method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Java 14 JLS, §9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5):

> Every member type declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly `public` and `static`.

Thus, one cannot access `this` in a field initializer.

The common way to work around this limitation is to provide a method that returns what is needed. Possibly, as [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) (requires Java 8+):

```
public interface Foo {
    public default String fooName() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/13Z3UU)

Comment: I would add as a sidenote this solution would work only from Java 8. It's stated in the 2nd link provided but it can be easily missed.

Comment: @NeoChiri true, added.